# Cannot rotate and move sprite within the same code using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

I have been given homework to make a top down shooter game but everytime I get my sprite to rotate, the movement lines stop working and everytime I get the sprite to move, the rotation lines begin to fail. I've never used Pygame in my life but I think the problem resides in my lack of understanding of the self command. Don't hold back telling me how wrong I am, like I said I haven't touched Pygame before and I've only been coding for around 5 months so there's a chance some of the lines are redundant anyways.

```
import pygame
import math

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("blue.png")
        self.movex = 0 # move along X
        self.movey = 0 # move along Y
        self.orig_img = self.image
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(x,y)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)
        self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey
        self.rotate()
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

    def move(self,x,y):
        #https://opensource.com/article/17/12/game-python-moving-player - movement source
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def rotate(self):
        rel_x, rel_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos() - self.pos
        angle = -math.degrees(math.atan2(rel_y, rel_x))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_img, angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)
```

```
player = Player(200,300)
steps = 10
sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprite_list.add(player)
```

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.move(-steps,0)
```

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
            player.move(steps,0)
```

I'd like to be able to move and rotate within the same code, I don't mind stutter at the moment. Sorry if I pasted too much code, I really don't know where the problem is so I decided it was better to give more information than less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to change `self.pos` rather than `self.rect`, because `self.rect` is updated by `self.pos` in the method `rotate()`:

> ```
> def rotate(self):
>     # [...]
>     self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos) # set self.rect by self.pos
> ```

Update `self.pos` in `update()`, before `rotate()` is called:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def update(self):

        #self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex <--- delete
        #self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey <--- delete
        self.pos = self.pos + pygame.math.Vector2(self.movex, self.movey)

        self.rotate()
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver honestly don't know how I didn't notice this